# Mockito. Capturing a call to LocalDateTime.now();

Tags: unit-testing, time, junit, mockito

I'm doing a unit test which calls a class and checks that a method in that class has been called with certain parameters. One of those parameters is `LocalDateTime.now()`.

My problem is that by the time control comes back to my JUnit test, time has marched on, so if I try to compare the time used in the class I'm calling with the current time, they ain't gonna match.

This is the method I'm looking at:

```
ServiceStatus serviceStatus = ServiceStatus.createNew(LocalDateTime.now());
```

The Junit test is:

```
verify(service).saveNotice(LocalDateTime.now));
```

I've tried using `TimeFactory` to fix the date:

```
given(timeFactory.currentDateTime()).willReturn(NOW);
```

followed by:

```
given(message.getHeader("MESSAGE_CREATED_TIME")).willReturn(NOW.toString());
```

&

```
verify(service).saveNotice(NOW));
```

But no joy.

Any suggestions?

(PS. In the actual code there are other parameters but I've stripped them out for the sake of simplicity and for reasons of commercial confidentiality.)

Comment: I noticed that you did not accept an answer. Please consider doing so - in case you need more information feel free to drop me a comment.

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748) on similar question, which might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is for you to use *PowerMockito*. This way you can return what you want from the call to `LocalDateTime.now()`.

For that you need more or less the following (example with *Calendar* class):

```
        import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
        import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
        import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
  //  ...

        @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
        @PrepareForTest({Calendar.class})
        public class DateUtilsTest {

    public void testWithKnownCalendar(){
           PowerMockito.mockStatic(Calendar.class);
           PowerMockito.when(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))).thenReturn(CalendarObjectFactory.getInstance().buildKnownCalendar(45)); 

        // your normal code here
    }
        }
```

Adapt it by using *LocalDateTime* instead of *Calendar*.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use PowerMock. Use/mock a [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) instead. Switch your call to `LocalDateTime.now()` to `LocalDateTime.now(clock)`. From the Clock docs:

> Best practice for applications is to pass a Clock into any method that requires the current instant. A dependency injection framework is one way to achieve this:
>
> ```
> public class MyBean {
>   private Clock clock;  // dependency inject
>   ...
>   public void process(LocalDate eventDate) {
>     if (eventDate.isBefore(LocalDate.now(clock)) {
>       ...
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> This approach allows an alternate clock, such as fixed or offset to be used during testing.

One strategy there is to make the `clock` final, and offer two constructors--one that uses a supplied clock, and one that gets the system clock out of `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` or `Clock.systemUTC()`. Another is to make the Clock field settable for testing, possibly by leaving it package-private. In either case, you could easily override the value by supplying a Clock created by `Clock.fixed(...)`, or write your own implementation if you need it to change across the duration of the test.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest to **not** use PowerMock.

Your problem is that **static** call to `now()`. It might look a bit over-engineered, but seriously consider to simply put some small interface / class around that static call, like:

```
interface TimeStampProvider {
  LocalDateTime getNow();
}
```

the "impl" for that can simply call LocalDateTime.now().

But the thing is: now you simply pass a TimeStampProvider object to your class (which you can mock perfectly **without** the need for PowerMock).

You see: Powermock *can* lead to all sorts of interesting bizarre problems in the long term; and especially when writing your **own** code: just put up a better design; instead of trying to "fix" a (partially) broken design using PowerMock.

Comment: +1 for not using PowerMock and using a small interface instead. It's such a standard solution, it's even built-in: see [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html).