# is there a way to mock Instant.now

Tags: scala, mockito

Is there a way to mock Instant.now in scala

The following gives me a problem because the Instant.now method is static
      val instant: Instant = mock[Instant]
      when(instant.now)....

Comment: This question is [effectively a duplicate of this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41574537/1426891), in which the answer isn't to mock `Instant.now`, it's to use a replaceable instance of [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) and then to call `Instant.now(clock)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito. Capturing a call to LocalDateTime.now();](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41574537/mockito-capturing-a-call-to-localdatetime-now)

Comment: see [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289157/mock-instant-now-without-using-clock-into-constructor-or-without-clock-object/70186748#70186748)

Answer (score 0):

Mocking static methods is not very straight-forward. There are a few ways to this though:

- PowerMock supports mocking static methods
- Wrap the static methods with instance methods. For example, instead of calling `Instance.now()` directly in your code, you may create `someObject.now()` wrapper function. Then, you can mock `now()` method on `someObject` as a normal mock.

If you could share more details, we may have a better idea on the resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You can try mocking the "companion object" (quotes because `Instant` comes from Java) by doing:

```
mock[Instant.type]
```

instead of

```
mock[Instant]
```